# Ask for additional facebook permission

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I'm having trouble while trying to retrieve an additional permission "publish_action".

I assume that user has already logged in via facebook thus basic permissions are granted.
Then I have this code (from my fragment):

```
List<String> permissionsRequested = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
List<String> permissionsActual = session.getPermissions();
if (!isSubsetOf(permissionsRequested,  permissionsActual)) {
    pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
        .NewPermissionsRequest(this, permissionsRequested);
    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
    return;
}
```

Seeing from debug, after user grants permission, control goes to onActivityResult, where, according to facebook docs, I have

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
facebookUiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

uiHelper is also properly (acording to the docs) used in all those onResume&onDestroy methods.

In onCreate I have

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
facebookUiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), fbSessionCallback);
facebookUiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

where fbSessionCallback has overridden `call()` method, that calls my `onFbSessionRestore()`:

```
if (pendingPublishReauthorization && 
    state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) {
    pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
    // do things with my new session, updated with granted permission. e.g. post to fb.
}
```

Trouble is that

1. onActivityResult executes, but after that no callback ever called, so that overridden call() won't go, and onFbSessionCallback either.
2. If I try to post again (start things from scratch) after that - it gets session without granted permission again, tries to request it and then goes facebook exception about pending newPublishRequest permission blah-blah

Can someone help to configure workflow from onActivityResult and later?
I read facebook docs and I tend to blame they are written badly. Maybe it's just me too stupid... :(((

Comment: I think you have to check https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook which can be easy way to integrate facebook sdk with your project.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is most likely not an option for this project.

Comment: I mean - I'm not the only one working on this project, facebook API is already used throughout it and it would be strange to add a lib to impement this requestNewPermission workflow - don't want to create more mess in project structure, there's enough already )

Comment: Have a look at the Hello Facebook sample or the Scrumptious sample. Both are good examples on how to request follow up publish permissions after initial log in.

Comment: Looked through it. Adjusted my code to be as much alike as possible. Still not working: in onCreate session callback gets assigned to uiHelper, calback's call() method get's called, then onSessionStateChange get's called.

After I request and grant permission - onResume get's called, onActivityResult - and that's all.

I even tried to go into facebooks method's, but got myself lost and scared. Those fb guys leave comments and javadocs only for public methods (((

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have set it up:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!permissions.contains("publish_actions")) {
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, "publish_actions");
            session.addCallback(callbacktwo);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            return;
        }
    }
```

This is in my onActivityResult but it doesn't need to be. I have used it in my onCreate before. I added a callback to the request which I can then use to do my next step.

Here is my callback:

```
private Session.StatusCallback callbacktwo = new Session.StatusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), ClassHere.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }
};
```

Remember that the callback will respond twice, once when you start a permission request, and after it is completed. So you have to work around that/work that into your code.

Comment: No, doesn't work for me at all.
call() in Session.StatusCallback instance never gets called.